# ajax block does not seem work in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

codeiginter keeps bypassing my ajax block

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".btnsubmit").click(function(e){

           e.preventDefault();

           var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
           var email = $("input[name='email']").val();
           var form = $(".vol-form");
           var url = form.attr('action');
           var type = form.attr('method');
           var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
           var full_url = baseurl+url;
           var formdata = {"name":name, "email":email};
           alert(full_url);
           $.ajax({
              url:full_url,
              method:"post",
              dataType:"json",
              data:formdata,
              success: function (response) {
                 alert(1);
                 alert(response.success);
              },
              error: function () {}
           });
           alert(3);
           //return false;
        });

    });

    </script>
```

everything else runs except for the ajax block. I had to post this after a thorough search online and i haven't found solutions yet.

here's the controller

```
    public function validate_form()

       {
            $response['success'] = $this->input->post('name');
            echo json_encode($response);
       }
```

here's the view form's header

`<form name="volunteer_form" method="post" action="welcome/validate_form" class="volunter-form vol-form">`

This is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

So I modified the ajax block to this

```
$.ajax({
        url:baseurl+'welcome/tryme',
        type:'POST',
        data:form.serialize(),
        dataType:'json'
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        console.log(response.success);
      })
      .fail(function(response){
        console.log(response.error);
      });
```

and i have this route defined

```
$route['welcome/tryme'] = 'welcome/tryme';
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('welcome/tryme');
```

at this point, the ajax block was able to run but still can not find the url, returns an xhr 404 (not found) error. But clicking on the link from the console runs perfectly and i get to see my responses I also moved the js file to assets.

below is the controller called Welcome.

```
public function tryme()
    {
        $response['success'] = $this->input->post('name');
        $response['error'] = "did not work";
         echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the controller function is being reached?

Comment: Also, are there any errors in the debugger console?

Comment: is `alert(full_url);` working ?

Comment: @DFriend yes the controller is being reached without ajax.

Comment: @OmarAbbas yes it works outside the ajax block. nothing works in the ajax block

Comment: My previous question was not clear. Does the **ajax call** reach the controller?

Comment: the **controller name** is ```welcome```. the **method** is ```validate_form```. the **form action** is ```welcome/validate_form```. the **base_url** is _http://example.org/site/_ . therfore the **full_url** outputs _http://example.org/site/welcome/validate_form_

Comment: @mituw16 yes there are. A 404 (not found) error. However, this line of code is highlighted in jquery library. ```try {
          r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null)
        } catch (e) {
          if (o) throw e
        }``` . this is jquery version 3.4.1

Comment: @DFriend it does not. I wonder why because from the console  the url response is correct but i get a 404 error

Comment: Could be any number of things. Try `console.log` on all the variables used in setting up the ajax. Make sure that all have useful values.

Comment: did you check $(".btnsubmit") exist??

Comment: If your codeigniter project is located in a subfolder add this into your .htaccess after RewriteEngineOn: `RewriteBase /foldername/` so in your example `RewriteBase /site/`

Comment: @Mikeyhun it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery post method to make a direct call. It's more useful. Your example doesn't have a real form-data.

```
$.post( full_url, formdata ).done((data) => {

});
```

Comment: the ajax call does not reach the controller. although when i hit the same url from the browser i see the page and the action is executed